# How to clone a Git repo from a VM?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine

I am currently developing inside a virtual Ubuntu box with Git, and I need to clone this repo to another CentOS VM. I don't know how to describe the git repo's location using the `user@server:/path.git` syntax.

Anyone can point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a way to get to the filesystem in the VM?

Comment: I have root access on both VMs.

Comment: The other person was asking if the VMs could access each other's filesystems, or perhaps a common filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping one VM from the other?  If so, then the IP you can ping you should be able to ssh to.

If you cannot ping, then perhaps you have a host which is reachable from both VMs.  You could create a server repo there.  For instance, github.com or bitbucket.com or the many many others might be a suitable third party host.  Perhaps you could install a proxy (squid or dante-socks or something similar) to allow the VMs to talk to each other.

If you have email connectivity, perhaps you could mail git-bundles back and forth instead of using normal live git connections.  There are many ways to do this, but we really need to know more about the networking and communications environment of these Vms to say more.